# Running build.xml file from Java program

Tags: selenium-webdriver

While calling a (build.xml file) ant using Java programs, it is throwing this exception:

```
build.xml:194: Fatal error during transformation
     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.XSLTProcess.handleTransformationError(XSLTProcess.java:1273)
```

My `build.xml` contains XSLT tag to generate XSLT report from testNG.

Please help me I am getting stuck in the same exception.